# how to override JndiObjectFactoryBean in spring and set decrypted password in java

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I have a datasource in tomcat which has password that is encrypted using some algorithm and I want to decrypt the same when i establish connection with DB.

Following is my spring config code

```
<!--<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jdbc.jndiName}"/>
</bean>-->

<bean id="dataSource" class="my.app.util.EncryptedDataSource">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jdbc.jndiName}"/>
</bean>
```

The above bean is a custom one that extends the JndiObjectFactoryBean

```
public class EncryptedDataSource extends JndiObjectFactoryBean{ ... }
```

What should I do here to get the encryted password and set it back.
I have my decrytion algorithm with me but I am not sure which super class method will fetch me the password that i can set back again.

Please suggest, i have search and tried a lot.

Comment: As mentioned in the other thread, don't. See http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Password for suggestions how to solve it in tomcat. Generally just protect the files on the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, Instead of overriding the JndiBeanFacotry, I used the tomcat data source "factory" property, it allows you to have a custom resource factory class that gets called every time data source lookup is instantiated.

Below link specifies step by step configuration,

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

"Adding Custom Resource Factories" section emphasises how to write a simple custom resource factory.

Thanks.