# How to decrypt tomcat datasource password in spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, encryption, jndi

All was working well until it was asked to decrypt my tomcats datasource password.
I use a algorithm to encrypt it and add it to the datasource.

but I dont know where to add the place holder to decrypt it.

```
<bean id="dbsource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/SomeDB"/>
    </bean>
```

Is it possible to read tomcats encrypted datasource password in spring and decrypt it before making connection?

Comment: No as Tomcat is in control of the datasource, spring only gets a reference... Also if you can decrypt it why bother at all, that isn't adding any real protection. Protect your tomcat configuration using file protection so that only tomcat can read it and no one else.

Comment: Also asking the same question twice isn't going to get you a result quicker! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387651/how-to-override-jndiobjectfactorybean-in-spring-and-set-decrypted-password-in-ja

Comment: Thanks Deinum, so when the tomcat starts, irrespective of the respective application is deployed or not, a connection pool gets created for that jndi resource name?